# How to run a unit-file as service for all users

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh, systemd, services

I am trying to run `ssh-agent` by each ssh-session for each user (let's say I have **userA** with root privilege and **userB** withOut these privilage ).

To do so, I've created a unit-file based on [this stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38980986/2804070)

I placed the service under `/etc/systemd/system/run-ssh-agent.service` :

```
[Unit]
Description=SSH key agent

[Service]
Type=forking
Environment=SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/run/ssh-agent.socket
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have also added `AddKeysToAgent yes` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and `export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"` to `/etc/bash.bashrc`

then, of course, I've restarted the session.

**The Problem:**
This approach works for **userA** but not for **userB**.

**Debugging:**

The environment-variable: **SSH_AUTH_SOCK** seems to be set correctly for userA

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/run/user/1006/ssh-agent.socket
```

but not for userB, where I get:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/ssh-agent.socket
```

I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS, 4.4.0-112-generic, OpenSSH_7.2p2

Thank you in advance for any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Systemd-wide user units should be placed in `/etc/systemd/user`.

You placed them in `/etc/systemd/system`, where they are only run as the root user.

Comment: thank you :)
I would like to run this unit file for all users. Thus it should be executed by the root user, isn't?

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: thank you for asking :) yes, I did, but unfortunately it didn't work as I wanted. I figured out later, that when I switch between users using `sudo su <another-user>`, I lose a lot of the environment variables due to the system configuration in the `sudoers`-file. Since this system is not my private one, I decided to not miss up the configuration and went with  [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18915067/2804070) approach that utilize `.bashrc`

Comment: You say it didn't work as you wanted, but did it run for every user? That was your question.

Comment: I believe, i did. I put the unit-file in the `/etc/systemd/user` directory, then I ran `systemctl --user <myservice.service> start`. It worked for the current user. for the other one, I was able to test the service status `systemctl <myservice.service> status`, though it was not working, as its activity as I remember was set to `failed`. Of course I tried to start ut again from this "other user", but it seemed that this "other user" does not have privileges to start this service.. may be..

Comment: If my answer was correct for the question you asked, could you mark it as accepted? Thanks.